# Is there a reason (performance or otherwise) to JOIN a derived table of only the needed columns in a table, and not just JOINing the table itself?

Tags: sql, performance

I'm refactoring and reformatting a long query, and I've noticed a pattern to the JOINs that doesn't seem to make sense. In the code I'm working on, many of the JOINs follow the same pattern as the JOIN involving the `customers_to_accounts` table in the example below:

```
SELECT
  customers.name,
  accounts.balance
FROM customers
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      customer_id,
      account_id
    FROM customers_to_accounts
  ) AS x ON x.customer_id = customers.customer_id
  INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.account_id = x.account_id
```

I'm really confused as to why the code wasn't written as:

```
SELECT
  customers.name,
  accounts.balance
FROM customers
  INNER JOIN customers_to_accounts ON customers_to_accounts.customer_id = customers.customer_id
  INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.account_id = customers_to_accounts.account_id
```

Adding the derived table here makes it seem like the code is doing something a lot more complicated than it actually is, at first glance. The only benefit I can think of is some kind of performance boost - but I would think that creating the derived table would be *detrimental* to performance, if anything. If the goal was to assign a shorter alias to the table than `customers_to_accounts`, you could of course do that without creating a derived table.

I don't know whether the code was written by hand, or whether it was somehow generated - is this something that many ORM libraries like to do? What other reasons might there be for this?

Comment: I would expect both queries to be equivalent in terms of performance in most databases.

Comment: You’re right, that doesn’t look like it makes sense. Maybe it was more complicated in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery is NOT going to give a performance boost -- at least not in any database that I'm familiar with.  On the other hand, there are database that will tend to materialize the subquery, which can have an adverse effect on performance.

Why would the code be written this way?  Probably just someone who overcomplicated the query, possibly due to an allergy of too many adjacent joins.

But there might be other reasons.  For instance, perhaps once upon a time the logic was much more complicated -- and the junction table was only recently created.  The person who originally wrote the code may have wanted to separate this particular logic.

Or, it might have been written this way to facilitate testing.  It is easy to put in a `limit 10` or `top (2)` into the subquery to validate that the code is doing what is expected.